# Changing Flink job topics dynamically mid-job

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

The use case is - a pipeline that reads from a changing list of topics, processes them, and writes to a different Kafka topic.
So there's currently 150 Kafka topics, but this list can change.
There's some API that returns the current set of topics (topics can be added and removed). I want to capture this change every minute (but it happens only a few times a day).

Using Flink, I can use [Dynamic Partition Discovery](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#dynamic-partition-discovery), with an interval of 1 minute - this seems to answer the use case.

But how to change the set of topics I'm subscribed to (without restarting the job ofc)?

```
    val topics = List("a", "b", "c")
    KafkaSource.builder[util.HashMap[String, Object]]
      .setBootstrapServers(kafkaSourceBootstrapServers)
      .setGroupId(kafkaJobConsumerGroup)
      .setTopics(topics:_*)
      ....
      .build
```

The above returns a `KafkaSource[T]`, but I want to change the `topics` list every minute (basically fetch `topics` value from some API).

How can I do so?

Seems like the only API I can use are:

```
env.fromSource()
env.addSource()
```

But this will create a different `DataStream[T]`, which I already have a streaming running on.

How can I change the topics list while my job is still running? Or It's not possible, and I can't escape a restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that might work would be to use a topic pattern:

```
KafkaSource.builder().setTopicPattern("topic.*");
```

But whether that's going to satisfy your requirements depends on whether or not you can arrange to have the topics you want to consume from follow some predictable naming pattern.

Comment: Probably not, because I don't want to read all the data to reduce costs. I want to read only the data I need (given some logic, so topics can change). So I guess my only option is to restart the job?

Comment: Yes, I think a restart is the only option.